# Tkinter: Global in function does not seem to work on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, global, tkinter-button

I want the var `state` to be `True` after clicking the button.

This is the code

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def value():
        global state
        state = True
        print(state)

btn_choose_mouse_position = Button(root, text=' Choose click positions', fg='black', bg="green",
                                   activebackground='#6D8573', command=value, padx=20, pady=20).pack()

try: print(state)

except:
    pass
try:
    if state:
        print('works')
except:
    pass
root.mainloop()
```

When I click the button, only `True` from the function is printed.

Comment: It appears that you printed `state` *once*, immediately after creating the Button.  The Button had not been clicked yet at that point in time, of course.  Whatever you want to happen in response to the click needs to be done from within the `command=` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using lambada to set the var `state` to `True`

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
state = BooleanVar()
btn_choose_mouse_position = Button(root, text=' Choose click positions', fg='black', bg="green",
                                   activebackground='#6D8573', command=lambda : state.set(True), padx=20, pady=20)
btn_choose_mouse_position.pack()

btn_choose_mouse_position.wait_variable(state)
root.mainloop()
```

`state = BooleanVar()` makes `state` a `bool` without a `True` or `False`

`.wait_variable(state)` waits for bool to change, a bit like os.wait[enter link description here]

Comment: Doesn't work. How can you tell if state is True or False?

Comment: it will return PYVALE0 or 1 (I'm not 100% sure) so you can do an if statement outside the function